# Bootstrap is not doing what it's supposed to do

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to replicate a website, but Some classes on bootstrap is working on coply.io but not on my browser. but you can see, I have applied card-deck, but the cards are not reacting and stay vertical instead of hr.

```html
<!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    
    <div class="card-deck">

<!-- firstcard -->
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
     <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>Free</h2>
      <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
      <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- secondcard -->
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
     <h3>Labrador</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
      <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
      <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- thirdcard -->
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
     <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
      <p>Pirority Listing</p>
      <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
      <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Are you including all the necessary files and in the right order?

Comment: [This shows how to do basic setup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As I go through you code I find that you may be use wrong format of `CDN`**

**Your `Code` should be like this.**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <h1>Hello, world!</h1> -->
    <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    
    <div class="card-deck">

<!-- firstcard -->
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
     <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>Free</h2>
      <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
      <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- secondcard -->
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
     <h3>Labrador</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
      <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
      <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- thirdcard -->
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
     <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
      <p>Pirority Listing</p>
      <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
      <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Let me know if this will work for you**

Comment: How do you know what "format" CDN they're using (or even if they're using a CDN at all), when they didn't even post that part of their code?

Comment: because there is no error in ```Bootstrap``` library or if your bootstrap is not working it's probably you are using the wrong CDN or you call your CDN in the wrong way. If you are enough experienced you will easily get to know what is the possibility of the error. Happy Coding

Comment: yes, it works, this was wrong. ( <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">), I had the wrong link. thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Must sure that you have implemented bootstrap cdn link in the head of your 
webpage.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- YOUR CODE HERE-->
</body>
```